# storing data about available RPG games

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo, sql-injection

I have been developing a **little**, private Blog Site to make notes/ stories of pen and paper RPG games available for my players and me.

This is my first project. As I am new to coding in PHP and MySQL I'd very much appreciate your opinions on the code I have written. I am interested in any  feedback you can give me - but especially on the security of the script I have written. The input form is actually secured by a randomly created username and password authentication via .htaccess. (Side note: the website uses proper encryption for the user input including HSTS and ranks as an A+ on ssllabs.com.)

I have been reading a lot lately on script injection and SQL injection (for example on https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/sql_injection_example) and using variables to create a query was often considered unsafe. Still - in my inexperiencedness - I've made a script that is using the (static) keys of the **$_POST Array** to determine the database columns and placeholders for values which are used in my PDO query. Afterwards I bind each submitted value to its PDO placeholder.

I do not expect to enter any HTML Input, which is why I decided to use the **stripslashes** and **htmlspecialchars** funcions on the input values before binding it to the PDO querys and I **haven't** used any str_replace function to **escape backtics** since every value is directly bound to the designated PDO placeholder.

```
if  (isset ($_POST['session_submit'])) {
    $table = 'sessions';
        
    foreach ($_POST as $column=>$value){
        $column = input_behandlung_sessions($column);
        $secure_value = input_behandlung_sessions($value);
        $formular_daten[$column] = $secure_value;
    }   
    
    $kampagne = $formular_daten['kampagne'];    
    $count = $pdo->prepare('SELECT COUNT(kampagne) FROM sessions WHERE kampagne = :kampagne');
    $count->bindParam(':kampagne', $kampagne, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $count->execute();
    $rowcount = $count->fetchColumn(0);
    $newrowcount = ++$rowcount;     
    
    unset($formular_daten['session_submit']);

    foreach ($formular_daten as $column=>$value){
        if ($value == "") unset($formular_daten[$column]);
    }

    foreach ($formular_daten as $column=>$value){
        $non_empty_columns[] = $column;
        $columns_param = ':'.$column;
        $array_columns_param[] = $columns_param;
        $to_bind[$columns_param] = $value;
    }

    $text_non_empty_columns = implode (", ", $non_empty_columns);
    $parameter_columns = implode (', ', $array_columns_param);  
       
    $sql_string = 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' (session_uid, '.$text_non_empty_columns.') VALUES ('.$newrowcount.', '.$parameter_columns.')';    
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql_string);
    foreach ($to_bind as $key=>$param){     
        $stmt->bindValue($key, $param);
    }
    $stmt->execute();

    unset($_POST);
    
}   

function input_behandlung_sessions($data) {
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
```

And here is the form used to submit the data (in case you are interested).

```
echo '
<form method="post" action="#v-pills-session">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-6"><label for="formGroupExampleInput">Kampagne: </label></div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6"><input required="true" type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" name="kampagne" placeholder="Kürzel der Kampagne eintragen"></div> 
          <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-6"><label for="formGroupExampleInput">Kapitel-Nr.: </label></div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6"><input required="true" type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" name="session_story_arc" placeholder="Nummer des Kapitels eintragen"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-12"><label for="formGroupExampleInput">Name: </label></div>
          <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-12"><input required="true" type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" name="session_name" placeholder="Hier den Namen der Session eintragen"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-12"<label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Spieler: </label></div>
          <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-12"><input type="text" required="true" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" name="session_charaktere_aktiv" placeholder="Hier die Namen der aktiven Charaktere eintragen"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-12"><label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Quests: </label></div>
          <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-12"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" name="session_quests" placeholder="Hier die Quests in dieser Session eintragen"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-12"><label for="formGroupExampleInput2">NPCs</label></div>
          <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-12"><input type="text" class="form-control" required="true" id="formGroupExampleInput2" name="session_npc" placeholder="Hier die Namen der NPCs aus dieser Session eintragen"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-12"><label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Orte: </label></div>
          <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-12"><input type="text" class="form-control" required="true" id="formGroupExampleInput2" name="session_orte" placeholder="Hier die Orte eintragen, in welchen die Abenteure unterwegs waren"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <input required="true" type="submit" name="session_submit" class="form-control btn-primary" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Submit">
      </div>
</form>';
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see [_what you may and may not do after receiving answers_](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765).

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ I hope that I do not violate another rule by answering to your comment but still - I'm sorry, I clearly seem to have lost track of some of the rules, will do better with future questions!

Comment: I've actually written something similar but I use `SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table` to generate the schema from the DB  and then filter the post array by that.  It gets a bit tricky when dealing with multiple tables though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at that second loop:

> ```
> foreach ($formular_daten as $column=>$value){
>     if ($value == "") unset($formular_daten[$column]);
> }
> ```

Some argue it is bad practice to omit the curly brackets, since anyone who needs to add a second statement when the condition is true might forget that there isn't a block here.

Additionally, [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter) could be used to replace the entire loop:

```
$formular_daten = array_filter( $formular_daten , 'strlen' );
```

<sub>(credit goes to [the post by anonymous](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php#111091))</sub>

Additionally, instead of adding values to `$formular_daten` in the first `foreach` and then having another `foreach` loop to unset any value that is equal to an empty string, you could just only add values to the array that are not equal to an empty string...

```
foreach ($_POST as $column=>$value){
    $column = input_behandlung_sessions($column);
    $secure_value = input_behandlung_sessions($value);
    if ($secure_value) { // equivalent to !== ""
        $formular_daten[$column] = $secure_value;
    }
}
```

And the `unset` call for the *session_submit* could be removed by not setting it in the first loop...

> ```
> unset($formular_daten['session_submit']);
> ```

So if the modified `foreach` above is used, that `unset` could be eliminated by updating the condition for setting the array value:

```
if ($secure_value && $column !== 'session_submit') {
    $formular_daten[$column] = $secure_value;
}
```

---

While it appears that you would need to have that loop before the check for count based on the value at `$POST['kampagne`], you could potentially move the code from that last `foreach` up into the first `foreach` loop, which would require looping through the data only once...

---

You could consider using `?` placeholders instead of named placeholders - see [Example 2 on the PDO prepare documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php#example-1048) (and compare to the example above it).

---

### Update

I would like to speak to what [@Your Common Sense](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/101565/your-common-sense) mentioned:

> I don't know why you call keys of the $_POST Array "static" (and what does it mean at all)

Not only can be `$_POST` be modified within the PHP script (because it is a [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) *variable* - not a Superglobal constant), but your script can be called by techniques other than submitting the form - including but not limited to:

- making a separate page that has a `<form>` tag with an `action=` attribute matching the URL corresponding to your script
- making an [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)/AJAX request matching the URL corresponding to your script
- making requests with tools like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)

And any of those means can be used to send various values in the POST data.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you call keys of the $_POST Array "static" (and what does it mean at all) but the article you linked to (which I wrote) explicitly demonstrates that $_POST Array keys are **unsafe** and using them in the query untreated makes your code **wide open to SQL injection**.

And no, your input_behandlung_sessions() is not the proper treatment. It makes anything but a *secure value*. Calling its output "secure" is a mockery: **html**specialchars() [has nothing to do with **SQL** injections](https://phpdelusions.net/sql_injection#badpractices), while stripslashes() is just a pointless function that does absolutely nothing useful at all.

As a result, your code is exemplary vulnerable.

You **must** use the solution offered in the article - a **white list** of predefined field names. So your code regarding the INSERT query must be something like this:

```
$formular_daten = []; // variables must be defined before use
$allowed = ['session_story_arc', 'session_name']; //add other fields

$fieldnames = "`session_uid`"; // a list of column names
$values = [$newrowcount]; // an array with values

foreach ($allowed as $column) { // allowed fields ONLY!
    if (!empty($_POST[$column])) { // if a column exists and not empty in a single line
        $fieldnames .= ", `$column`";
        $values[] = $_POST[$column];
    }
}
$parameter_columns = str_repeat('?,', count($values) - 1) . '?';

$sql_string = "INSERT INTO `$table` ($fieldnames) VALUES ($parameter_columns)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql_string);
$stmt->execute($values);
```

the code in the end is not only **safe** but also uses less loops to process.

On a side note, your method to get a session_uid is extremely clumsy and error prone. Depending on the purpose of this field, either make it integer auto_increment or some unpredictable unique value like one generated by `session_create_id()`

Answer (score 0):

When you expect get reviewed from poeple speaking English, try to use only English in your code (and in comments).

Why go through `formular_daten` twice when you can check if the value is empty and, if not do the processing in a single loop?

Comment: I changed the variables to english and deleted the forms since they were half german and I do not expect them to be relevant. Additionally I've merged the two loops like you suggested - thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Considering the suggestions from @Sam Onela and the devastating comment of @Your Common Sense I re-read the article on SQL-Injection and looked up some basic examples on YouTube to understand the importance of the code you provided (like [html-form-exploits](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CNRlg8BiJOw) and [sql-injection](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ciNHn38EyRc)). I recommend this to everyone else new to this.

The confusion regarding `session_uid` is understandable. The purpose of this was to be able to sort sessions of different campagins in chronological order and to be able to link quests to sessions. Therefore I changed the field to `session_date` and the format to "date". The quests will be linked to the `session_id` (which was not shown in the code, as it is an int, auto_increment column).

I changed the code suggested by @Your Common Sense a bit (a little closer to the example in the article listed in my question) since I had an easier time troubleshooting errors in the PDO statement. Thank you very much for all your input - here's the updated, hopefully better, code:

PS: Could someone point out to me why the backtics in the keys are still being escaped  after specifying `$allowed` keys (like in the [solution from phpdelusion](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/sql_injection_example#solution))?

```
if  (isset ($_POST['session_submit'])) {
$table = 'sessions';

$allowed = ["session_story_arc", "session_name", "session_date", "session_charaktere_aktiv", "session_quests", "session_npc", "session_orte", "kampagne"];
$pdo_str_column = $pdo_str_values = $pdo_str_value = "";
$params = [];

foreach ($allowed as $key) {
    if (($_POST[$key]) != ''){
        $pdo_str_column .= "`".str_replace("`", "``", $key)."`, ";
        $pdo_str_value = ":".str_replace("`", "``", $key);
        $pdo_str_values .= ":".str_replace("`", "``", $key).", ";
        $params[$pdo_str_value] = $_POST[$key];
    }
}

$pdo_str_column = rtrim ($pdo_str_column, ", ");  
$pdo_str_values = rtrim ($pdo_str_values, ", "); 

$sql_string = 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' ('.$pdo_str_column.') VALUES ('.$pdo_str_values.')';

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql_string);
foreach ($params as $key=>$value) {
        $stmt->bindValue($key, $value);
}
$stmt->execute();

unset($_POST);
unset($params);

}
```